# Faster way to update with Groovy SQL

Tags: mysql, groovy

I am updating rows of a MySQL database with groovy and with the method I am using things are very slow. I was hoping you could improve on the performance of my example:

```
sql.resultSetConcurrency = ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE

sql.eachRow("SELECT * FROM email) { bt ->
    bt.extendedDesc = update(bt.name, bt.direction)
}

sql.resultSetConcurrency = ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY
```

Then there is the update method:

```
def update(name, direction) {
    if (direction == 'Outgoing') {
        result = 'FROM: '+name
    } else {
        result = 'TO: '+name
    }
    if(result.size() > 75) {
        result = result.substring(0, 72) + "..."
    }
    return result
}
```

So it updates one field of each entry in email (extendedDesc in this example) using a method that needs 2 other fields passed to it as parameters.

It is very slow, around 600 entries updated per minute, and email has 200000+ entries =/

Is there a better method to accomplish this? Should use Groovy if possible, as it needs to run with all my other Groovy scripts.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. From what I can see, you're not using the class `Sql` at all in `update()`. So how is Groovy involved here? And suddenly, you mention "bigtable". What's that? Where does it come from? Where can I see it in the code examples above?

Comment: Based on the method that are being called it looks like the variable `target` is an instance of `Sql`. Not sure how BigTable comes into play here. Are you using your code on Google App Engine?

Comment: @Aaron @Benjamin Apologies, I have made appropriate changes. `target` was indeed a sql instance, and bigtable was a placeholder I was using as I was formulating this question. I should have reread the question before I submitted, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing your update as a cursor based, updatable query, which has to read every record and conditionally write something back.  You're doing all the heavy lifting in the code, rather than letting the database do it.

Try using an update query to only update the records matching your criteria.  You won't need eachRow to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure what criteria you are referring to, every row needs to be updated.

Comment: still faster to let the database do it than to try and visit every row yourself.  For example, "update email set from = 'From:'

Comment: I suppose I am also confused, as I did not think it was possible to implement the login in the above update() method only using sql.

Comment: Let me try that again:  still faster to let the database do it than to try and visit every row yourself.  For example, "update email set extendedDesc = 'From: ' + name where direction = 'Outgoing'" .. I know you have slightly more complicated logic for testing the size of the results, but mysql has built-in string functions for handling that sort of thing (I'll leave that part to you :-)

Comment: if you have the variable sql already initialized and connected to your database, use it to execute the update.  (use sql.executeUpdate(update-query)